# How to print to pdf separated excel pages in one file?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, printing

I made this simples code, but this create 4 pdfs files, not only one, can you help me?

```
Sub PrintToPageX()
Worksheets("Anexo Financeiro").Select
Application.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne02:"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut from:=1, to:=4
If Worksheets("Anexo Financeiro").Range("p205") = 1 Then ThisWorkbook.PrintOut from:=5, to:=5
If Worksheets("Anexo Financeiro").Range("n272") = 1 Then ThisWorkbook.PrintOut from:=6, to:=6
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut from:=7, to:=7
End Sub
```

Comment: Is ``Worksheets("Anexo Financeiro")`` the same as `ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets`? Are they referring to the same worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Worksheets("Anexo Financeiro")` is the same as `ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets` which is the same as `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet`:

I created an [If Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements) that checks if the document can be printed all together or if it needs to be separated.

```vb
Sub PrintToPageX()
    Application.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print To PDF on Ne02:"
    With Worksheets("Anexo Financeiro")
        If .Range("p205") = 1 And .Range("n272") = 1 Then
            .PrintOut From:=1, To:=7
        Else
            .PrintOut From:=1, To:=4
            If .Range("p205") = 1 Then .PrintOut From:=5, To:=5
            If .Range("n272") = 1 Then .PrintOut From:=6, To:=6
            .PrintOut From:=7, To:=7
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Works!

Comment: @ArmandoCerdeira Please mark the question as answered (click the check mark on this post)

Comment: I again, but this create a lot of pdf files and not only 1